# How to reinitialize Outlook to the factory setting (the point when it was fresh after my 1st office install)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've accidentally deleted the My Outlook Data File(1).pst.

[image]

Now I'm unable to launch Outlook anymore because I can't get past this error dialog box. I've tried fixing the problem myself using these two websites

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windowsrt8_1-update/deleted-outlook-data-file-please-help/98741493-8195-415b-bbb1-f749b21fdfa8

and
https://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/how-to-recover-deleted-files-from-a-pst-file-in-outlook/

But they did not help because My Outlook Data File(1).pst no longer exists on my computer. Is there a way to reinitialize Outlook to the factory setting (the point when it was fresh after my 1st office install)? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [these steps](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1898-outlook-rest-to-factory-settings.html)?

Comment: It worked! much appreciated!